# ulimit: Invalid argument

Tags: command-line, memory

I'd like to limit memory usage of a process using `ulimit`, but I'm unable to do so. Every time I get error "cannot modify limit: Invalid argument".

```
$ ulimit -Sv
unlimited
$ ulimit -Hv
unlimited
$ ulimit -Sv 1024
bash: ulimit: virtual memory: cannot modify limit: Invalid argument
```